# Remove a string from another string

Tags: python

I have two string variables - `string_A` and `string_B`. `string_A` contains the following:

`"ONE" # "TWO" # "THREE" # "FOUR" # "FIVE"`

and `string_B` contains:

`"NANA" # "PAA" # "THREE" # "ELI"`

I want to remove all the elements that are in `string_A` from `string_B`. After I print `string_B` it should look like `"NANA" # "PAA" # "ELI"`

Update:

```
x = textA.split(' # ')
y = textB.split(' # ')

for i, j in enumerate(x):
if j in y[i]:
    pass
```

Comment: Help with what? Have you attempted to solve this problem at all?

Comment: Yes, let me update my code

Comment: It's usually better not to remove the items from a list. It's more efficient to make a new list with list the items you want to keep

Comment: @Blender No worries :) Cool down.

Answer (score 7):

```
a = '"ONE" # "TWO" # "THREE" # "FOUR" # "FIVE"'
b = '"NANA" # "PAA" # "THREE" # "ELI"'

a_elements = set(a.split(' # '))
b_elements = [key for key in b.split(' # ') if key not in a_elements]

b = ' # '.join(b_elements)
```

Answer (score 2):

A straight-forward solution:

```
a = '"ONE" # "TWO" # "THREE" # "FOUR" # "FIVE"'
b = '"NANA" # "PAA" # "THREE" # "ELI'

a_elements = [key.strip() for key in a.split('#')]
b_elements = [key.strip() for key in b.split('#')]
filtered_b_elements = [key for key in b_elements if key not in a_elements]
new_b = ' # '.join(filtered_b_elements)
```

Answer (score 1):

there you go:

```
' # '.join([x for x in string_B.split(' # ') if x not in string_A.split(' # ')])
```

If you want better performance, create a list out of string_A first and use this for the "`not in`" clause.

Answer (score 1):

For `re` fans:

```
import re

e = '"ONE" # "TWO" # "THREE" # "FOUR" # "FIVE"'
f = '"NANA" # "PAA" # "THREE" # "ELI"'

ea_pattern = re.compile(r'"([a-zA-Z]+)"')
ea = re.findall(ea_pattern,e)
fa = re.findall(ea_pattern,f)

answer = [x for x in fa if x not in ea]
print(answer)
```

Use this `list` in whatever way you want -

> `['NANA', 'PAA', 'ELI']`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '"ONE" # "TWO" # "THREE" # "FOUR" # "FIVE"'
b = '"NANA" # "PAA" # "THREE" # "ELI"'
x = a.split(' # ')
y = b.split(' # ')

for j in x:
    if j in y:
        #HOW TO REMOVE
        y.remove(j)

xx = ' # '.join(x)
yy = ' # '.join(y)
print xx
print yy
```

The following outputs:

```
'"ONE" # "TWO" # "THREE" # "FOUR" # "FIVE"'
'"NANA" # "PAA" # "ELI"'
```

Comment: I want it without wrapped with the single quotes, and i want to have the `#` sign in between instead of the `,`. Also when i print it the whole thing should be a string and not a list.